# How to rollback in case of error during a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a transaction which will include multiple insert statements into different tables in the db. What I want to achieve is a rollback in case for example the insert statement fails.

What I have right now is the following but I'm not sure if this would behave how I want.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO [FTR].[dbo].[Usr](fname, lname, phonea, addr)
    (
        SELECT p_code, y_code, y_name, r_coden
        FROM [ADS].[Prep].[InfoEm]
    )
    --
    -- other multiple insert statements
    --
COMMIT TRAN
```

Will this query rollback in case any of the insert statement fail, or even the select statements maybe.

Comment: @DaleK Yes this seems great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as below:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO [FTR].[dbo].[Usr](fname, lname, phonea, addr)
    (
        SELECT p_code, y_code, y_name, r_coden
        FROM [ADS].[Prep].[InfoEm]
    )
    --
    -- other multiple insert statements
    --
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Comment: Rather than repeating an existing answer, its better to flag as a duplicate.